# Aqueduct failed to execute db migration file

Tags: postgresql, aqueduct

I'm trying to learn Dart and Aqueduct. I'm following the Aqueduct tutorial. Up to now everything worked ok. But when connecting to the database I get an error.

I'm using:

```
Windows 10
PostreSQL 13
Dart 2.10.0
Aqueduct 4.0.0-b1
```

I get the following error:

```
*** There was an error connecting to the database 'heroes_user:password@localhost:5432/heroes'. Reason: unable to connect to database.
```

**Command prompt with error**

[image: Command prompt with error]

I can connect to the database using `psql` or `DBeaver`, so username (heroes_user), password (password) and database (heroes) are correct.

I started with Aqueduct 3, but after I search for the error I noticed other people had similar problems and the suggestion was to upgrade to Aqueduct 4. So I executed pug get + updated `pubspec.yaml` + pub global activate aqueduct `4.0.0-B1`. This did not result in any progress.

Other suggestions I found were to change the password authentication method. I modified `pg_hba.conf` to include the line:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

But this did not have any success either.

I'm not sure in which direction to search anymore. I've noticed similar questions, but without actual answers.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Problem seemed to be with PostgreSQL 13.
I installed PostgreSQL 12.4 and ran the command to create the database migration file. Then ran the database update command and it worked immediately.